# subsetting R data frame using multiple sets of dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date, subset

I have the following dataset:

```
 ID               dates                  d1                  d2                  d3                 d4
 X1 2007-09-09 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                 <NA>               <NA>
 X1 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                 <NA>               <NA>
 X1 2007-09-11 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                 <NA>               <NA>
 X1 2007-09-13 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                 <NA>               <NA> 
 X2 2007-10-09 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
 X2 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
 X2 2007-10-11 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
 X2 2007-10-14 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
 X2 2007-10-15 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
 X2 2007-10-20 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
```

My aim is to subset the data into two datasets, such as one of them has all dates between d1 and d2 AND between d3 and d4, and the other has all remaining dates.

Here is what the result would look like:

data1 (dates between d1,d2,d3,d4):

```
ID               dates                  d1                  d2                  d3                d4
X1 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
X1 2007-09-11 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
X2 2007-10-09 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
X2 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
X2 2007-10-14 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
X2 2007-10-15 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
```

data2 (remaining dates):

```
ID               dates                  d1                  d2                  d3                  d4
X1 2007-09-11 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
X1 2007-09-13 09:00:00 2007-09-10 09:00:00 2007-09-11 09:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
X2 2007-10-11 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
X2 2007-10-20 09:00:00 2007-10-08 09:00:00 2007-10-10 09:00:00 2007-10-13 09:00:00 2007-10-16 09:00:00
```

Would there be a simple way for me to do this?
Here is the code for my first dataset so you can reproduce it:

```
ID<-rep(c("X1","X2"),times=c(4,6))
dates<-c("2007-09-09 09:00:00","2007-09-10 09:00:00","2007-09-11 09:00:00","2007-09-13 09:00:00","2007-10-09 09:00:00","2007-10-10 09:00:00","2007-10-11 09:00:00","2007-10-14 09:00:00", "2007-10-15 09:00:00","2007-10-20 09:00:00")
d1<-rep(c("2007-09-10 09:00:00","2007-10-08 09:00:00"),times=c(4,6))
d2<-rep(c("2007-09-11 09:00:00","2007-10-10 09:00:00"),times=c(4,6))
d3<-rep(c(NA,"2007-10-13 09:00:00"),times=c(4,6))
d4<-rep(c(NA,"2007-10-16 09:00:00"),times=c(4,6))
data<-data.frame(ID,dates,d1,d2,d3,d4)
```

Comment: Not clear about the condition `between d1 and d2 AND/OR d3 and d4,`. Is it for cases when there are `NA` in d3, d4.  suppose you have NA in d2, then would the between is d1 and d3

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. d1 and d2 are pairs of dates like d3 and d4. I don't want any crossover, like d1-d3, or d2-d4. If there are NA's for the columns d3 and d4, then I just want dates between d1 and d2.  I've also edited the question above, hopefully that makes more sense!

Comment: Suppose if there is NA in `d2` and 'd1' is non-NA, then would you compare only d3 and d4

Comment: Given the nature of my data, that wouldn't happen. Either both d1 and d2 would be NA or neither would be. Same goes for d3 and d4.

Comment: This is not difficult once you convert the character strings to `Date` objects, but your expected results do not match with your description. In `data1` the first row: 2007-09-09 09:00:00 is not between d1 and d2, 2007-09-10 09:00:00, 2007-09-11 09:00:00.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'll edit the question and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your dates from character to `Date` objects first using `as.Date`. Then use `dput()` to provide the data in a compact format for posting:

```
data <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(13765, 13766, 13767, 13769, 
13795, 13796, 13797, 13800, 13801, 13806), class = "Date"),
d1 = structure(c(13766, 13766, 13766, 13766, 13794, 13794, 13794, 13794,
13794, 13794), class = "Date"), d2 = structure(c(13767, 13767, 13767, 13767, 
13796, 13796, 13796, 13796, 13796, 13796), class = "Date"), d3 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 13799, 13799, 13799, 13799, 13799, 13799), class = "Date"), 
d4 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 13802, 13802, 13802, 13802, 
13802, 13802), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Now set up your selection criteria and use them to create `data1` and `data2`:

```
select1 <- with(data, dates >= d1 & dates <= d2)
select2 <- with(data, dates >= d3 & dates <= d4)
select2 <- ifelse(is.na(select2), TRUE, select2)
select <- select1 & select2
(data1 <- data[select, ])
#        dates         d1         d2   d3   d4
# 2 2007-09-10 2007-09-10 2007-09-11 <NA> <NA>
# 3 2007-09-11 2007-09-10 2007-09-11 <NA> <NA>
(data2 <- data[!select,])
#        dates         d1         d2         d3         d4
# 1  2007-09-09 2007-09-10 2007-09-11       <NA>       <NA>
# 4  2007-09-13 2007-09-10 2007-09-11       <NA>       <NA>
# 5  2007-10-09 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
# 6  2007-10-10 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
# 7  2007-10-11 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
# 8  2007-10-14 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
# 9  2007-10-15 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
# 10 2007-10-20 2007-10-08 2007-10-10 2007-10-13 2007-10-16
```